# How does @CreatedBy work in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I used `@CreatedDate` on entity property and I see that it inserts date into db. I don't understand what is the purpose of `@CreatedBy` annotation in Spring Data JPA.

In the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#auditing) I read :

> We provide `@CreatedBy`, `@LastModifiedBy` to capture the user who created or modified the entity

But how to create and use such user?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you already made it to the reference documentation, I recommend to read [two more paragraphs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#auditing.auditor-aware) to find out about and how to use `AuditorAware`. :)

Answer (score 14):

for TL;DR

your Entity

```
@CreatedBy
private UUID modifyBy;
```

and your SecurityAuditorAware

```
@Component
public class SecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<UUID> {

    @Override
    public Optional<UUID> getCurrentAuditor() {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        return Optional.of(((MyCustomUser) authentication.getPrincipal()).getId());
    }
}
```

note:
you need use the same data type, I use UUID as my custom user id.

Comment: Where did `MyCustomUser` come from?

Comment: @Chris it's from your custom user implement, check  [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html)

Comment: For me it didn't work until I added `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
` to my entities (well, to the entities base class)